# How to use CSS Grid in Genesis Column Classes?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, genesis

How to use css grid in genesis column classes? i tried below code but column heights are unequal.

```
.one-half.first {
    border: 1px solid #00569d;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.one-half {
    width: 50%;
}

.one-half {
    float: left;
}

.col-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .one-half { 
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}


<div class="col-container">
<div class="one-half first">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Important Dates</h3>
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li><strong>Starting Date:</strong> 09-11-2018</li>
<li><strong>Last Date:</strong> 30-11-2018</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="one-half">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Application Fee</h3>
<ul style="list-style-type: square;">
<li><strong>Rs.50/- :</strong> For All Candidates</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

the final result of above code

[image: View Image Here]

Comment: But that is not CSS grid syntax :( It's table layout.

Comment: can you please suggest me code

Answer (score 1):

For the parent container i.e. `col-container` set the [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to 50% each.

```css
.col-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.one-half {
  border: 1px solid #00569d;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="one-half first">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Important Dates</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
      <li><strong>Starting Date:</strong> 09-11-2018</li>
      <li><strong>Last Date:</strong> 30-11-2018</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="one-half">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Application Fee</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
      <li><strong>Rs.50/- :</strong> For All Candidates</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

h3 {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.one-half {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #00569d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="one-half first">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Important Dates</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
      <li><strong>Starting Date:</strong> 09-11-2018</li>
      <li><strong>Last Date:</strong> 30-11-2018</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="one-half">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Application Fee</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
      <li><strong>Rs.50/- :</strong> For All Candidates</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to add on the CodePen. Can you follow the CodePen structure?

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/tushar-kumawat/pen/MzEaNe)